# installing ember-cli with npm

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I'm trying to install ember-cli package using NPM

`npm install -g ember-cli`

before the installation complete. I get these errors.

```html
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  bufferutil.cc
C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(263): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> _Nan
EnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)': function template has already been defined [C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(256): note: see declaration of '_Na
  nEnsureLocal'
C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C3083: 'smalloc': the sym
bol to the left of a '::' must be a type [C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\buffe
rutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C2039: 'FreeCallback': is
 not a member of 'node' [C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil\build\buffe
rutil.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Murhaf\.node-gyp\5.0.0\include\node\node_object_wrap.h(8): note: see declaration of 'node'
C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C2061: syntax error: iden
tifier 'FreeCallback' [C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferu
til.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(665): error C2065: 'callback': undecl
ared identifier [C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vc
xproj]
C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(665): error C2065: 'hint': undeclared
 identifier [C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxpro
j]
C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(672): error C2665: 'node::Buffer::New
': none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types [C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember
-cli\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Murhaf\.node-gyp\5.0.0\include\node\node_buffer.h(43): note: could be 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buff
  er::New(v8::Isolate *,char *,size_t)'
  C:\Users\Murhaf\.node-gyp\5.0.0\include\node\node_buffer.h(31): note: or       'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buff
  er::New(v8::Isolate *,v8::Local<v8::String>,node::encoding)'
  C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(672): note: while trying to match t
  he argument list '(v8::Isolate *, const char *, uint32_t)'
C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(676): error C2440: 'return': cannot c
onvert from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object>' [C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\e
mber-cli\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(676): note: No constructor could ta
  ke the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(683): error C2039: 'Use': is not a me
mber of 'node::Buffer' [C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil\build\buffer
util.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Murhaf\.node-gyp\5.0.0\include\node\node_buffer.h(8): note: see declaration of 'node::Buffer'
C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\nan\nan.h(683): error C3861: 'Use': identifier
not found [C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Murhaf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ember-cli"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bufferutil@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@1.1.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bufferutil package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bufferutil
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\Users\Murhaf\Desktop\ember-cli\npm-debug.log
```

I'm working on PC win10 x64, I have `node v5.0.0` and `Python 2.7.10` and `VS2015 (including WindowsSDK 8.1)`
,I also have `node-gyp v3.0.3`

The problem seems to be in VS compiler! I couldn't understand what am I missing there?

Comment: [ember-cli-windows](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-cli-windows) might help.

Comment: Did you try running it again? For me updating / installing `ember-cli` fails once because of `node-gyp` and then it proceeds to work

Comment: Nope, the installation doesn't complete, after the errors it rollback. @PeteTNT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall *node*, *ember-cli* and everything else related to them and follow [these](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/) instructions from the *ember-cli* user-guide section. Everything will work fine then ;).

PS: Use node version 4.x.x, I also had problems with 5.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

On a recent installation of node I ran into the issue with `node-gyp`. Turns out the issue was having to be on [npm v 2.14.3](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-ic-ajax/issues/6#issuecomment-154508504) Double-check you're not on v3.x with `npm -v`.

As Vitor Martins mentions, stick with node 4.x.x, too.